# How to write rspec test cases for Rails cache implementation in custom ruby gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, rspec

I have implemnted gem which is using rails low level caching

```
#for reading from cache
gnav_cache_data  = Rails.cache.read(cache_key)

#to write in cache
Rails.cache.fetch(cache_key, :expires_in => 15.minutes) do
    gnav_data_response
end
```

But it is throwing the following error.
**"NoMethodError:
       undefined method `read' for nil:NilClass"** in read line in test case.

But when I install gem in sample application it is working perfectly.Storing data in cache also.

Explanation of Function of gem:It will make some api call and store data in cache of the application where gem is installed. But for writing testcases how can i implement caching only to my gem environment.and other rails functions if possible.

Comment: Can you give some more context please? Have you attempted to load the rails stack in your spec?

Comment: I dont know how to add rails stack in spec but in my program where these lines resides i added require 'rails'. @max